# How can I get an alert if a specific url substring is present and nothing if null

Tags: substring, javascript

```js
function getCode() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=")) {
        var url = (document.URL);
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
        window.alert(id);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Purpose:** When people go to our "Service Request" page using a QR code that has a substring of `?discount=1234`. I have been testing by creating an alert box with the discount code showing. Eventually I want to be able to populate that "1234" automatically into a "Discount Code:" text field on page load.

The above is a mixture of a few suggestions when I researched it.

**Result:** Going to `example.com/serviceRequest.html?discount=1234` gives me the appropriate alert "1234", as I want... Going to `example.com/serviceRequest.html` gives me the alert `http://example.com/serviceRequest.html`, but I don't want anything to happen if "?discount=" is null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indexOf` returns -1 if the search pattern doesn't exist. In JavaScript, anything not a `0` or `false` or `undefined` is considered true.

So your line of:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=")) {
```

Would better search as:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=") > -1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your if-statement to:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=") != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up the documentation for ".indexOf". It returns -1 for not found and >= 0 if it is found.

```
...indexOf("?discount=") >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

substring and indexOf return -1 if the text is not found, so you can test for this. E.g.

```
   function getCode() {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=") != -1) {
            var url = (document.URL);
            var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
            window.alert(id);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test the indexOf value:

```
function getCode() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("?discount=") !== -1) {
    var url = (document.URL);
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
    window.alert(id);
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the quick and dirty answer would be

```
var discount = window.location.search.split("?discount=")[1];
alert(discount);
```

But this doesn't take into account the occurence of other query string parameters.

You'll really want to parse all the query parameters into a hash map.

This article does a good job of showing you a native and jQuery version.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html